# Asset validation failed when distributing an app

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, braze

When I try to archive to generate a version to distribute the app, I am getting this error in the below picture.

I also checked the `CFBundleExecutable` and `CFBundlePackageType` in `Info.plist`. Both are set as expected in image.

The pod is `'Appboy-iOS-SDK'` also ocurrs with `BrazeKitCompat`, or `BrazeKit`.

[image: asset validation failed]

What can I change in my project to archive normally?

Answer (score -2):

The configuration of the lib was correct, but in the `podfile` there was a configuration that modified the `Info.plist` causing the problem. By removing the line below, it was possible to solve this problem and `Archive` and `Distribute` normally.

```
config.build_settings['GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE'] = 'YES'
```